# SPSS dialog not appearing

Tags: multiple-monitors, display-settings, dialog

Sometimes, I notice that when I click a menu item or select from the most-recently-used dialog list in the toolbar, I expect a dialog box (e.g. Frequencies) to appear but it does not. The application seems otherwise relatively responsive and the statistics processor is not busy.  Some dialog boxes do appear.  Restarting SPSS doesn't always help.

The workaround is to open a syntax editor and use that to run the command, but the syntax isn't always obvious.

Answer (score 0):

The dialog is probably appearing on a different monitor, even if you don't have another monitor connected at the time, and even if you haven't had one connected (nor had any Windows settings indicating there was a second display) since before your most recent reboot.

Try connecting another monitor to see if it shows up there.

Comment: This looks like potentially useful information, but confusing.  Are you referring to a setup where multiple monitors have previously been configured but one is temporarily disconnected, or SPSS decides, entirely on its own for some unknown reason, to display information on an imaginary monitor?

Comment: Multiple monitors have been previously configured but are not connected at the time, and cycling through various settings on the Computer Only/Duplicate/Extend/Projector Only switch (to be sure it's set up for a single monitor at the time the issue's observed) does not help.